# How to combine tomcat and nginx?

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I would like to configure my system so nginx is serving all of the the static files, while Tomcat is handling the dynamic `.jsp` pages.

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: Please consider accepting some of your previous answers. Why should I go to the trouble of helping you, when you don't give anything back? If you don't know what I mean, I suggest you read the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Does tomcat accessible via HTTP? If yes, then
Imagine we have some tomcat which serves on the same machine on port 88 queries which ends up with .jsp

The config file will be like:

```
location / {
  root /path/to/static/files;
}

location ~* \.jsp {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:88;
}
```

The main idea is that nginx proxies requests that it couldn't handle to specific backend (backend will see request from 127.0.0.1).